# Table or view doesnot exist

Tags: oracle, plsql, execute, execute-immediate

Hi given below is my code. I need to create a view and get data in another cursor using data in the view. But when i execute my code , i am getting the error

"ORA-06550: line 56, column 37:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 52, column 9:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored"

What is the issue here? 
Thanks in advance.

```
declare

drop_view_sql varchar2(100) := 'drop view rv_task_number_view';

type tasks_rec is record(task_number varchar2(20));

type t_tab is table of  tasks_rec;

tasks_tab t_tab;

notes_rec xx_fs_mob_loc_rec.task_notes_rec;

notes_tab xx_fs_mob_loc_rec.task_notes_tab;

    begin

        execute immediate 'create view apps.rv_task_number_view  as
                          SELECT distinct ct.task_number                  
                          FROM csf_ct_tasks ct ,

                            cs_estimate_details ced,
                            csf_debrief_headers cdh,
                            csf_debrief_lines   cdl,
                            jtf_task_assignments jta  

                   WHERE    1=1
                   and      jta.task_id = ct.task_id
                   and      jta.task_assignment_id = cdh.task_assignment_id(+)
                   and      cdh.debrief_header_id = cdl.debrief_header_id(+)
                   and      cdl.debrief_line_id = ced.source_id(+)
                   AND      ((ct.planned_end_date between (sysdate-30) and (sysdate+30)) or (ct.scheduled_end_date between (sysdate-30) and (sysdate+30)))
                   and      jta.resource_id = 10153';

              execute immediate     'grant select on apps.rv_task_number_view to apps';

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sqlerrm);

        declare

        CURSOR c2 is

        SELECT ct.task_id,jtf_note_id,  jnv.notes,
               jnv.creation_date,jnv.last_update_date
            FROM
               jtf_notes_vl jnv,
               csf_ct_tasks ct,apps.rv_task_number_view rvt
            WHERE
                jnv.source_object_code = 'TASK' 
                and ct.task_number = jnv.source_number
                and ct.task_number = rvt.task_number
                order by task_id, jtf_note_id;

        begin

        open c2;

        fetch c2 bulk collect into notes_tab;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sqlerrm);

        end;

        execute immediate drop_view_sql;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sqlerrm);

    END;
```

Comment: Does it work when you enter the command directly in SQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to access a `TABLE/VIEW` that was created using a *dynamic* `SQL` in the same block where you `SELECT` it (Static `SQL`)

Every `PL/SQL` Block wold be *compiled* before *execution*.
And while compilation `rv_task_number_view` was not available!

So, the `SELECT` needs to be dynamic as well!

```
  C2 SYS_REFCURSOR;

   OPEN C2 FOR 

    'SELECT ct.task_id,jtf_note_id,  jnv.notes,
           jnv.creation_date,jnv.last_update_date
        FROM
           jtf_notes_vl jnv,
           csf_ct_tasks ct,apps.rv_task_number_view rvt
        WHERE
            jnv.source_object_code = ''TASK'' 
            and ct.task_number = jnv.source_number
            and ct.task_number = rvt.task_number
            order by task_id, jtf_note_id';
```